# In netty's addLast, which EventExecutorGroup is right

Tags: java, netty

Using Netty, I'm enhancing a TcpIp server that reads XML over VLI. The server uses VLI to determine the boundaries of a packet. Then it turns the packet into an xml doc the following way.

```
pipeline.addLast("VLI codec", new CombinedChannelDuplexHandler<>(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(8192, 0, 2, 0, 2), new LengthFieldPrepender(2, false)));
pipeline.addLast("XML codec", byteToDocumentCodec);
```

followed by further processing handlers.

This is working well but not well enough. Using a single thread, requests have to wait for each other to be processed. Clearly, an *EventLoopExecutor* argument must be introduced to the second *pipeline.addLast*.

The question is which would be appropriate. I am considering either

```
pipeline.addLast(new LocalEventLoopGroup(), "XML codec", byteToDocumentCodec);
```

or, alternatively, something like

```
pipeline.addLast(new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(8), "XML codec", byteToDocumentCodec);
```

Answer (score 1):

The DefaultEventExecutorGroup is the right one if you not want to do it in the I/O thread. That said you want to share the same instance of it for different ChannelPipelines.